# Commands and results printed twice after invalid command to execvp

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to create shell-like c code. It reads from the given file by each line, breaks it down to command token, create argv, and runs execvp. However, there is one problem. Whenever I put invalid command, It prints all the below commands and it's output twice.

For example, if it's written

```
catdf
echo one
echo onetwo
```

It prints out

```
catdf: No such file or directory
echo one
one
echo onetwo
onetwo
echo one
one
echo onetwo
onetwo
```

which is not what I desire. (I want each command line and output to be printed only once)

What I assume to be reason of error is fork.

After fork, in child, I used

```
execvp(argv[0], argv);
perror(argv[0]);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

In parent, I used

```
while ((iPid=wait(&status))>0){
    if (status!=0)
        break; /*for current command line*/
}
```

This code works well for errors such as

```
cat nonexistingfile
```

But for

```
nonexistingcommand
```

it prints all the below commands and outputs twice.

Does it have something to do with perror in this case of nonexisting-command ? It works for existing command with invalid arguments.

Thank you!

Comment: "What I assume to be reason of error is fork." How should we know? You do not show any code containing `fork`. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). My magical crystal ball tells me you might have a stray `;` after `if ( fork .....)`